Calculation and selection of shafts and gears
This is a solar tracker
The top weight is about 6 kg
What is the minimum torque required to rotate the upper part?
What shaft is needed?
And the diameter of the gear?

What bearings? Gear diameters look chosen... Do a search for Homepower magazine and they reported on several.

Minimum torque will depend on the friction, the moment of inertia of the system and the maximum angular acceleration required.
